# Group rows from SQL database by date in tables

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, html-table

**UPDATE - Added query**

I am developing a system which gathers results from games from a MySQL database. I'd like the results to be 'grouped' by the date (e.g. results from a certain date will be in one table).

I'm nearly there, but struggling to get the results from the same date to display as the next row of the table.

[image: You can see the current output here].

Here's the code as it stands:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT  `MatchDate`, t1.`TeamName` AS HomeTeam, `MatchHomeScore`, `MatchAwayScore`, t2.`TeamName` AS AwayTeam `FROM  `match` INNER JOIN  `team` t1 ON  `match`.`MatchHomeTeamID` = t1.`TeamID` INNER JOIN  `team` t2 ON  `match`.`MatchAwayTeamID` = t2.`TeamID` ORDER BY `MatchDate` ASC ");`

$currentDate = false;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<div class="col-lg-4">';
        echo '<div class="panel panel-default-fixtures">';
            if ($row['MatchDate'] != $currentDate){
            echo '<div class="panel-heading">';
                echo '<h4 class="panel-title">';
                    echo $row['MatchDate'];
                echo '</h4>';
            echo '</div>';
        $currentDate = $row['MatchDate'];
    }
    echo '<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables">';
                echo '<thead>';
                    echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<th class="all">';
                            echo 'Home';
                        echo '</th>';
                        echo '<th colspan="2">';
                            echo 'Score';
                        echo '</th>';
                        echo '<th class="all">';
                            echo 'Away';
                        echo '</th>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                echo '</thead>';
                echo '<tbody>';                                        
                    echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row['HomeTeam'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row['MatchHomeScore'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row['MatchAwayScore'].'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'.$row['AwayTeam'].'</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';                                     
                echo '</tbody>';
            echo '</table>'; 
        echo '</div>'; 
    echo '</div>'; 
}
```

**2nd update**

Used the code Shamil Omarov provided and fixed the issue with a few changes. Here's the working code:

```
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "
                        SELECT  `MatchDate`, t1.`TeamName` AS HomeTeam, `MatchHomeScore`, `MatchAwayScore`, t2.`TeamName` AS AwayTeam
                        FROM  `match` 
                        INNER JOIN  `team` t1 ON  `match`.`MatchHomeTeamID` = t1.`TeamID` 
                        INNER JOIN  `team` t2 ON  `match`.`MatchAwayTeamID` = t2.`TeamID`
                        -- WHERE YEAR(`MatchDate`) =2017 
                        ORDER BY `MatchDate` ASC ");

$currentDate = false;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{                                

    if ($row['MatchDate'] != $currentDate){

        if ($currentDate != false){
            echo '</tbody>';
            echo '</table>'; 
             // /.table-responsive
            echo '</div>'; 
             // /.panel
            echo '</div>'; 
            // /.col-lg-4 
        }

        echo '<div class="col-lg-4">';
        echo '<div class="panel panel-default-fixtures">';
        echo '<div class="panel-heading">';
        echo '<h4 class="panel-title">';
        echo $row['MatchDate'];
        echo '</h4>';
        echo '</div>';                   
        echo '<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables">';
        echo '<thead>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th class="all">';
        echo 'Home';
        echo '</th>';
        echo '<th colspan="2">';
        echo 'Score';
        echo '</th>';
        echo '<th class="all">';
        echo 'Away';
        echo '</th>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</thead>';
        echo '<tbody>';     
        $currentDate = $row['MatchDate']; 
    }                             

    if ($row['MatchHomeScore'] != null && $row['MatchAwayScore'] != null){
        echo '<tr class="success">';
    } else {
        echo '<tr>';
    }
    echo '<td>'.$row['HomeTeam'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['MatchHomeScore'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['MatchAwayScore'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['AwayTeam'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
```

This new code now outputs:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this.

```
 $currentDate = false;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo '<div class="col-lg-4">';
        echo '<div class="panel panel-default-fixtures">';

        if ($row['MatchDate'] != $currentDate){

        if($currentDate != false){
            echo '</tbody>';
            echo '</table>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }

        echo '<div class="panel-heading">';
        echo '<h4 class="panel-title">';
        echo $row['MatchDate'];
        echo '</h4>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTables">';
        echo '<thead>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th class="all">';
        echo 'Home';
        echo '</th>';
        echo '<th colspan="2">';
        echo 'Score';
        echo '</th>';
        echo '<th class="all">';
        echo 'Away';
        echo '</th>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</thead>';
        echo '<tbody>';
        $currentDate = $row['MatchDate'];
    }


    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['HomeTeam'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['MatchHomeScore'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['MatchAwayScore'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['AwayTeam'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Shamil, I've added an update to the post with the new code and output.

Comment: Welcome @AdDaws :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the query. Could you show it in order to find out what is needed to be changed?

Comment: Added the query, although I'm not sure that is the issue. I believe it has something to do with the positioning of the if statement.